# Replace Word with #Word after first #

Tags: regex, notepad++

Anyone would kindly help with a regex for Notepad++ to replace `Word` with `#Word` (only after the first occurrence of `#`)?

```
#Celebrity #Glad #Known #Lord Byron #British #Poet
```

should become

```
#Celebrity #Glad #Known #Lord #Byron #British #Poet
                              ^
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your regex.

Comment: Also show more examples of valid input and expected output

Comment: What should be the result for `Celebrity Glad #Known #Lord Byron #British #Poet`?

Comment: Celebrity Glad #Known #Lord-Byron #British #Poet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace Word with #Word only after the first occurrence of #, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

**Find what**

`(?>^[^#]*#\w+\h*|#\w+\h*|\G)\K(\w+\h*)`

**Replace with**

`#\1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1gzCpm/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `^[^#]*#\w+\h*` Match from the start of the string not a `#` 0+ times using a negated character class followed by matching a `#`. Then match 1+ times a word character followed by 0+ times a horizontal whitespace character.
  - `|` Or
  - `#\w+\h*` Match `#`,  a word character 1+ times followed by a horizontal whitespace character 0+ times
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close atomic group
- `\K` Forget what what previously matched
- `(\w+\h*)` Capture in a group 1+ word characters followed by 0+ times a horizontal whitespace character

Comment: Thank you fourth bird. That works!  How about a different output? replace #Word1 #Word2 Word3 Word4 with #Word1 #Word2-Word3-Word4 ?

Comment: @Markov You could omit matching the horizontal whitespaces in the beginning and only match them in the iterating part and capture the following word characters in a capturing group [`(?>^[^#]*#\w+|#\w+|\G)\K\h*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/BnycVV/1/) Then replace with `-\1`

Comment: Thank you very much The fourth bird. 50339 strings were replaced!

Comment: Where a name comes with spaces after a #, remove spaces and eventual apostrophes, periods. e.g. #Best #Style #Newspaper #P. J. O'Rourke #American #Comedian. Can this be made to output #Best #Style #Newspaper #PJORourke #American #Comedian

Comment: Your question does deviate from the original question, you could always ask a new questinon. You might try using a character class [`(?>#\w+\h*|\G(?!\A))\K(?:['. ]+|([\w]+\h*))`](https://regex101.com/r/3LmojE/1/)

Comment: Some long string here #Best #Style #Newspaper #P. J. O'Rourke #American #Comedian
output 
Some long string here #Best #Style #Newspaper #PJORourke #American #Comedian

As suggested by the talented The Fourth Bird, I have tried using a character class (?>#\w+\h*|\G(?!\A))\K(?:['. ]+|([\w]+\h*)), yet this did not replace the undesired chars. 

 The site does not allow me to ask further questions.

Comment: here is another example: 
<h4>A. S. Byatt: English Novelist</h4><h4>Born: August 24, 1936</h4><h4>#Machine #Scientific #Word #A. S. Byatt #English #Novelist</h4>

should output 

<h4>A. S. Byatt: English Novelist</h4><h4>Born: August 24, 1936</h4><h4>#Machine #Scientific #Word #ASByatt #English #Novelist</h4> (note #ASByatt)

Comment: For my last example you have to replace with the first capturing group `\1`

Comment: #Fathers Day #Life #Family #Frank-Abagnale #American #Celebrity should output to #FathersDay #Life #Family #Frank-Abagnale #American #Celebrity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the following regex to match and replace:

```
\s([^#]\w+)
```

It starts by matching a White Space then it creates a Group, that does not start with '#', but contains one or more Word characters.

You then replace with:

```
' #$1'
```

That will add '`#`' to the Words thats doesn't start with it.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work on my end. I get the error "/\s([^#]\w+)/g" does not exist. Of course RegEx is checked. I tried both in Notepad++ and EmEditor.

Comment: I also thought of removing the space in the beginning and tried replacing /([^#]\w+)/g or ([^#]\w+)/g

Comment: @Markov: Why do you use delimiters and global flag? Remove them and it will work if you replace `\s` with `\h`